# wcf duplex large message gives no meaningful reply on large message with ReliableSessions

Tags: .net, wcf, wcf-binding, nettcpbinding, duplex

I am using a NetTCP duplex binding to send a document from the server to the client as byte[].
When this byte[] is pretty large (say 10Meg) the server quits by giving

`The server did not provide a meaningful reply; this might be caused by a contract mismatch, a premature session shutdown or an internal server error.`

Smaller messages for example 1 mb does work well.
This is the binding in my web.config

```
 <bindings>
  <netTcpBinding>
    <binding name="InsecureTcp" receiveTimeout="0:10:00" sendTimeout="0:05:00" portSharingEnabled="true" openTimeout="0:0:02" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647" maxBufferSize="2147483647">
      <readerQuotas maxDepth="2147483647" maxStringContentLength="2147483647" maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxBytesPerRead="2147483647"/>
      <security mode="None"/>
      <reliableSession enabled="true" ordered="true" inactivityTimeout="0:00:05"/>
    </binding>
  </netTcpBinding>
</bindings>
<behaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior name="">
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
      <dataContractSerializer maxItemsInObjectGraph="2147483647" />
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
</behaviors>
```

**Update 1**
It looks like that the Reliable Session kills the connection by suspecting inactivity. The push of the document to the client takes more than 5 seconds, so the channel is faulted by (I suppose) the client.
However: I have this inactivityTimeout of 5 seconds, to get almost immediately notified when the connection drops, so I can instantiate a new connection to the server.

It looks like these two requirements fight each other